# Spring RestTemplate get generic object

Tags: spring, generics, resttemplate

I gave this model

```
public class ResponseMessage<T> {

    private T result;
    private ResultCode resultCode;
    private String details;

    public ResponseMessage(T result, ResultCode resultCode, String details) {
        this.result = result;
        this.resultCode = resultCode;
        this.details = details;
    }
//getters and setters
```

and when I get this model from server I conwert it

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String result = restTemplate.getForObject(lkAuthListUrl, String.class);
        Type listType = new TypeToken<ResponseMessage<LkAuth[]>>() {
        }.getType();
        ResponseMessage<LkAuth[]> model = Converter.me().getModel(result, listType);
```

and in Converter I do it

```
public <T> T getModel(String jsonStr, Type type) {
        T t = null;
        try {
            t = gson.fromJson(jsonStr, type);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print(e);
        }
        return t;
    }
```

Can I to avoid convertation in my method and move this duty to `RestTemplate`?

something lile this

```
ResponseMessage<LkAuth[]> model = restTemplate.getForObject(lkAuthListUrl, ResponseMessage<LkAuth[]>.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be avoided by using the `exchange()` method in the restTemplate object, but would require a few changes, such as converting your array to a `List` and passing a `ParameterizedTypeReference` with the type as parameter (necessary because of type erasure). The rest of it is similar to what you were expecting:

```
ResponseEntity<List<LkAuth>> response =
        restTemplate.exchange(lkAuthListUrl,
                    HttpMethod.GET, null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<LkAuth>>() {});
List<LkAuth> model = response.getBody();
```